# Kiddush cup with the name of angels engraved on the inside

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, malach-angel, kiddush-cup

I just bought an antique kiddush cup in Yerushalayim with names of the angels written all throughout the inside on the whole length of the kiddush cup (in several columns around the cup).  The store owner said it was Kabbalistic, but I was just wondering if there's any further significance?  Is it a segulah?  Does it have anything to do with welcoming the angels during Shalom Aleichem?  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you say "the angels" -- which angels?

Comment: The store owner told me just "angels," I think he said something about there being 72?  I definitely recognized some of them (Michael, Gavriel, etc), but some were names that didn't look familiar.  Know anything about this?

Comment: Dup of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27298/501 "Inscription in kiddush cup relating to 4 Rivers of Eden "

Comment: @DannySchoemann, is this identification a slam-dunk? (I wouldn't know, as I'd never heard of such a cup.) I think it'd have to be to make this a dupe.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - based on Zvi's answer, I would say yes. (Not an expert in cups - or any mysticism - but this cup comes up every so often)

Comment: It is created by a silversmith from lakewood named Yankel Litzinsky.

Answer (score 4):

It is known as the כוס הישועות or Cup of Salvation.

On the outside of the cup are the names of the four rivers that flowed through the Garden of Eden. Inside the cup are engraved sixty-four different words that are derived from the letters of the names of the four rivers. It is supposed to be a Segula for many things.

It is written in the Siddur of the [Rashash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashash):

> על דבר שמות נהרות גן עדן וסגולתם, אשמיעך דברים גדולים ועצומים, מאת ה'
>   אלוהיך,ובהם תדע סוד פלאי אל חי.‏
>
> About the matter of the names of the rivers of Gan Eden and their
>   Segulos (Omens) , I will let you know great and awesome things from
>   Hashem your God, and through them you will know a wonderful secret of
>   the Living God.

For further sources and an in depth discussion about this 'Segula' See [Ohr Yisrael Tammuz 5774](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_13614_230.pdf)

### Longer Text:

> על דבר "נהרות גן עדן" וסגולתן אשמיעך דברים גדולים ועצומים ובהם תדע סוד
>   פלאי... ובאלו האותיות אין חולי בעולם שלא תרפאהו...‏
>
> ואלו השמות חקוקים בכיסא הכבוד והם טובים ומסוגלים לשמירה לחן ולעושר בכל
>   משלח ידך ואין ערוך להם...‏
>
> ותתמה הפלא ופלא ממה שתראה בעיניך ותהיה מוצלח ובכל אשר תפנה תשכיל
>   ותצליח ובכוחו לפקוד עקרות... ולהמיר הקדחת ... וזהו סוד הספר שגנז חזקיה
>   מלך יהודה והוא חכמת זה הסוד, מן האותיות האלה והקבלה הגדולה הנגנזת
>   בהם... ואלה האותיות חקוקים בשער נהרות גן העדן היוצאים מן התהום שמתחת
>   מערת המכפלה..."‏
>
> כוס סגולה של כסף אשר חרוטים בו צירופי שמות.‏
>
> כתיבתם על נייר או קלף ולמוחקם בתוך מים או יין ולשתותו.‏
>
> חריטתו כטס של כסף ונשיאותו בקמיע.‏
>
> חריטתו בכוס של כסף ולשתות ממנו.‏
>
> אחר שביאר סודות השמות ואופני צירופיהם וכוחותם, כתב ״ואת השמות האלו
>   תמחה במים או ביין ויעשו פלאות באיש או אישה אשר ישתו אותם.. ובראותך אלו
>   הפלאות אזי תאמין שיש אלוה בישראל כי יסירו כל מיני קדחות שבעולם בנתינתך
>   אלו השמות מחויים כנזכר או כתובים בלחם על הדרך אשר הוריתיך...׳‏

Comment: Where in the Siddur of the Rashash? Also, where is your "longer text" from?

Comment: @Shokhet To the question "[w]here in the Siddur of the Rashash?": See Siddur Nahar Shalom, Vol 4, [p. 147](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21955&pgnum=148)-151.